# Can i do one loop instead of two?

Tags: shell, for-loop, unix, ksh

I have a list of files at ${MY_DIR}.

```
ABC_foo123.txt
ABC_foo456.txt
ABC_bar100.txt
```

Need to do some operations on these files.

My Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

ls -l ${MY_DIR}/ABC_foo*.txt
RV=$?
if [[ $RV -eq 0 ]];then
        echo "files found for processing"
        for sFile in `ls -1 ${MY_DIR}/ABC_foo*.txt`
do
        fileNameOnly=$(basename ${sFile})
        echo processing $sFile
        #Doing some operations here
done
else
    echo "No foo files found to process"
fi

ls -l ${MY_DIR}/ABC_bar*.txt
RV=$?
if [[ $RV -eq 0 ]];then
        echo "files found for processing"
        for sFile in `ls -1 ${MY_DIR}/ABC_bar*.txt`
do
        fileNameOnly=$(basename ${sFile})
        echo processing $sFile
        #Doing some operations here
done
else
    echo "No bar files found to process"
fi
```

This is doing as expected. However, is there a way I can use one loop instead of two. I feel I am doing same thing twice.
Any suggestions are welcome

Comment: I think `ls -1 ${MY_DIR}/ABC_bar*.txt` should be `ls -1 ${MY_DIR}/ABC_bar*.sql`.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about `ksh`, but in `bash` you can do:

```
for sFile in ABC_{foo,bar}*.txt; do
```

In a generic shell, you could simply do:

```
for sFile in ABC_foo*.txt ABC_bar*.txt; do
```

To check if any files have been processed, it's probably cleaner to do something like:

```
flag=0
for sFile in "${MY_DIR}"/ABC_foo*.txt "${MY_DIR}"/ABC_bar*.txt; do
    flag=1
    # process sFile
done
if test "$flag" = 0; then echo "error" >&2; done
```

Using the glob prevents a lot of errors that will arise from filtering the output of `ls`, but may run into problems in very large directories (eg, directories with several hundred thousand entries).  If that's a concern, you probably want to look at variations of `find`.

Comment: Let me try this out

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have the same processing to do for each type :

```
#!/bin/ksh

MY_DIR=$1

nbr_txt=0
nbr_sql=0

for file in $MY_DIR/*.txt $MY_DIR/*.sql; do
    case ${file##*/} in
        *.txt) ((nbr_txt++))
                # Processing txt type files
                ;;
        *.sql) ((nbr_sql++))
                # Processing sql type files
                ;;
    esac
done

print "$nbr_txt txt files processed"
print "$nbr_sql sql files processed"
```

Edited as per comments

Comment: Well, that's the only place where "bar" file are with .sql....assumed it was a typo. But, doesn't really matter, just make the case statement with the proper test...I'll edit with differences between .sql and .txt instead.

Answer (score 0):

When you have similar code on different places, consider a function.
Something like

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

operate_file() {
   filebase="$1"
   extenstion="$2"
   ls -l ${MY_DIR}/${filebase}*.${extension}
   RV=$?
   if [[ $RV -eq 0 ]]; then
      echo "files found for processing"
      for sFile in ${MY_DIR}/${filebase}*.${extension}; do
         fileNameOnly=$(basename ${sFile})
         echo "processing $sFile"
         #Doing some operations here
      done
   else
     echo "No foo files found to process"
   fi
}

operate_file ABC_foo txt
operate_file ABC_bar sql
```